# Internet Explorer 7 z-index override

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

I am trying to reset the z-index property of an element. It works everywhere except (surprise!) IE7 or IE8-as-IE7. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

[Test Case on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/uAxNV/6/)

Frankly I do not hope to have it working in IE7, maybe anyone has ideas for a workaround?

Some context:

The element in question has an input child and is itself located within a jQuery UI Dialog. The Dialog library [disables modifications](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js#L700) of any fields with lower-than-overlay zIndexes. This feature combined with the above bug means that I can not edit the field even if I properly reset the zIndex for the test element.

Thank you for any ideas you can give!

Comment: I don't know how to fix that exact test case in IE7 - it's reduced down too far. I'll probably be able to fix it if you provide a second test case including your jQuery UI Dialog, showing the bug.

Comment: That was my goal - to reduce it. :-)

A "workaround" is to set the #test z-index: 1500 to be higher than that of the overlay's.

Comment: I'm glad you found a workaround. That's kinda what I meant though - I didn't have a chance to find any workaround like that because your test case was *really* reduced (which isn't normally a bad thing).

Comment: Here is a little more elaborate test case: [http://jsfiddle.net/uAxNV/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/uAxNV/8/)

Answer (score 0):

So IE7 has a strange bug where you have to set the z-index of the parent element too. Check out [here](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/)

You could also try adding zoom: 1; that sometimes works.

Comment: Thank you, I know about this problem and use the technique described in various parts of my application. However, the quirk above is not related to stacking but rather to inability to reset the z-index, like I show in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uAxNV/8/) example. `zoom: 1` is sometimes used to set `hasLayout` but the `#test` element already has the layout because of `position: relative`.